# Golang test, call to database Prepare should fail, but it does not

Tags: database, unit-testing, go, mocking

I'm writing some test code with the help of go sqlmock.

The following code does not validates if the prepared statement has the correct query.

The main code is this:

```
// main.go
package main

import "database/sql"

func testFunction(db *sql.DB) {
    db.Prepare("SELECT")
}

func main() {}
```

And the test code:

```
// main_test.go
package main

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    sqlmock "gopkg.in/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock.v1"
)

func TestPrepare(t *testing.T) {
    db, mock, mErr := sqlmock.New()
    assert.NoError(t, mErr)
    defer db.Close()

    mock.ExpectPrepare("^BADSELECT$")

    testFunction(db)

    if err := mock.ExpectationsWereMet(); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("there were unfulfilled expections: %s", err)
    }

}
```

As far as i know, the test **should fail,** but it does't. What i'm i doing wrong? 
I'm using GO 1.7/macOS 10.12.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question,

Calling ExpectPrepare() returns a ExpectPrepare struct. In order to assert that Prepare() is being called with the right query, on must use ExpectQuery on the struct. 
See the example bellow.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
)

func testFunction(db *sql.DB) {
    stmt, err := db.Prepare("SELECT")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
}

    stmt.Query()

}

func main() {}

package main

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    sqlmock "gopkg.in/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock.v1"
)

func TestPrepare(t *testing.T) {
    db, mock, mErr := sqlmock.New()
    assert.NoError(t, mErr)
    defer db.Close()

    mock.ExpectPrepare("^SELECT$").ExpectQuery()

   testFunction(db)

    if err := mock.ExpectationsWereMet(); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("there were unfulfilled expections: %s", err)
    }

}
```

EDIT:

After reporting an issue, it turns out this was actually a BUG in the go-sqlmock package. It's fixed. We should now be able to use ExpectPrepare().
[go-sqlmock issue #50](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock/issues/50)

Thanks